# Adding '/[x]' to any aspx page still shows the page, expected 404

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

no idea where to start on this one, but here goes. if i've missed an answer somewhere is becuase i don't know how to search for the error.

take a aspx page i.e. `www.example.com/about` when testing i have found (accidently i must say) that adding `/anything` i.e. `www.example.com/about/eduhdbbw` still returns the `www.example.com/about` page (assuming `www.example.com/about/eduhdbbw` doesn't exist). i would expect a 404 in this situation but i don't really know how it is routing to the original page.

fyi i'm using VS 2017 community with iis and asp.net webforms with c# and the error occurs in vs and compiled in iis. if any other info is needed please ask.

Edit: the about page does indeed show .aspx in the browser url. Also i am using a blank webform template, so it didn't come with anything pre-installed and i've not written and url re-write.

Pathinfo sound like it might be something but would this affect a project with just basic aspx and code behind, amd basically no other dependancy?

Also for now i am just using absolutepath to compare the page name and sending to 404 if it doesn't math; but it seems like a sloppy solution to have on every page...

Comment: `/about` is not an aspx page URL  - that will only work if you're using ASP.NET's Routing system with WebForms or if your web-server (IIS or IIS Express) is using URL-rewrite rules in your `web.config` (or `applicationHost.config`) file. Please confirm if you're using ASP.NET Routing and/or IIS URL Rewriting and if so, look at your routing and rewrite rules.

Comment: Another possibility is that you're using the long-deprecated "extensionless URLs" trick with WebForms projects (which predates ASP.NET Routing) - in which case your project will have an `IHttpHandler` or `IHttpModule` which intercepts requests and internally transfers them to the correct page-handler.